# I want to know an automated way to load the data set when the files moved to another computer?

Tags: r

Someone, please guide me. Suppose I choose the location of a data file using the file.choose () and load the dataset after that. Also, suppose I have sent the script+data set to a friend of mine from e-mail. when my friend downloaded the files and run the r script,  he has to choose the location of the file to run the script. I want to know an automated way to load the data set when the files moved to another computer.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider having a "project" directory where you have a directory for scripts and one for data. There's a  called `rprojroot` that has filesystem helpers which will aid you in writing system independent code and will work well if you have a "project" directory. RStudio has a concept of projects & project directories which makes this even easier.

Second, consider using a public or private GitHub for this work (scripts & data). If the data is sensitive, make it a private repo and grant access as you need. If it's not, then it's even easier to share. You'll get data and code version control this way as well.

Third --- as a GitHub alternative --- consider using [Keybase](https://keybase.io) shared directories or git spaces. You can grant/remove access to specific individuals and they remain private and secure as well as easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

These solutions will work on any computer without changing the script.

**1) use current dir** If you assume the data and script are in the same directory then this will work on any computer provided the user first does a `setwd("/my/dir")`  or starts R in that directory.  One invokes the script using `source("myscript.R")` and the script reads the data using `read.table("mydata.dat")`.  This approach is the simplest, particularly if the script is only going to be used once or a few times and then never used again.

**2) use R options** A slightly more general approach is to assume that R option DATADIR  (pick any name you like) contains that directory or the current directory if not defined.  In the script write:

```
datadir <- getOption("DATADIR", ".") # use DATADIR or . if DATADIR not defined
read.table(file.path(datadir, "mydata.dat"))
```

Then the user can define DATADIR in their R session or in their .Rprofile:

```
options(DAtADIR = "/my/dir")
```

or not define it at all but setwd to that directory in their R session prior to running the script or start R in that directory.

This might be better than (1) if the script is going to be used over a long period of time and moved around without the data.  If you put the options statement in your .Rprofile then it will help remind you where the data is if you don't use the script for a long time and lose track of its location.

**3) include data in script** If the script always uses the same data and it is not too large you could include the data in the script.  Use `dput(DF)`  where `DF` is the data frame in order to get the R code corresponding to `DF` and then just paste that into your script.  Here is such a sample script where we used the output of `dput(BOD)`:

```
DF <- structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7), demand = c(8.3, 10.3, 
19, 16, 15.6, 19.8)), .Names = c("Time", "demand"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame", reference = "A1.4, p. 270")

plot(demand ~ Time, DF)
```

Of course if you always use the same data you could create a package and include the script and the data.

**4) config package** You could use the config package to define a configuration file for your script.  That still begs the question of how to find the configuration file but config can search the current directory and all ancestors (parent dir, grandparent dir, etc.) for the config file so specification of its location may not be needed.

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck.